# NSFetchedResultsController Crash When Setting the Controller

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Here is my code I'm running and I used console messages to pinpoint that it crashes right when the let frc command is running.  Interestingly enough I have another project where I'm using more or less the same code and it works but I can't tell what I'm doing any differently.  Was hoping maybe someone here had some possible insight into this?

```
//Create fetchedResultsController to handle Inventory Core Data Operations
    lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Workorders> = {
        return self.setFetchedResultsController()
    }()
func setFetchedResultsController() -> NSFetchedResultsController<Workorders>{
        print("setFetchedResultsController()")

        let context = gm_getContext()
        let workordersFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Workorders> = Workorders.fetchRequest()

        print("set fetch request")

        let frc = NSFetchedResultsController <Workorders>(
            fetchRequest: workordersFetchRequest,
            managedObjectContext: context,
            sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
            cacheName: nil)

        print("set the frc")

        frc.delegate = self

        return frc
    }
```

I've looked into the documentation for Apple and it says I can set sectionNameKeyPath to nil and cache to nil, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you enable exception breakpoints and show exact place, where it crashes?

Comment: I know it crashes there because of the console messages if you look at my screenshot.  I can set a breakpoint but what line would you like that on?

Comment: Can you do the same:    http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Comment: How do I set exception breakpoints by the way? I know if I click in the editor to the left on the line number it creates one, but not sure what info I'm looking for.  I'll print out the entire log though.  Ohh just saw your comment let me read that link one sec...

Comment: @JosephAstrahan did you check the article from the comment above?

Comment: Let me know if the new screenshots were what you are looking for, I did this kind of quickly, but I'll read that article in more detail in meantime.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't helpful though :)

Comment: Yeah I'm very confused as to what could be causing the issue on that line in particular of all lines.  Does setting the FRC do anything special to the UI at that very moment? I've gotten this error before because of UI mistakes, but I'm rather confident I have none at the moment, but I'll revisit this if you think it could be related.

Comment: Could you show, how you obtain context? This func gm_getContext

Comment: sure its a global function I put in globals, looks like this, //Shortcut method to get the viewcontext easily from anywhere.
func gm_getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    //For unique constraints it will overwrite the data.
    context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    
    return context
}

Comment: The function seems to work everywhere else I use it.

Comment: Not related but what is the reason to use a function **and** a lazy var to create the results controller?

Comment: I was using the lazy var to only create it when its called the first time and the function is because I use the function again when the viewWillAppear to update it with possible new data again.  Good question though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the apple documentation:

> A fetch request. This must contain at least one sort descriptor to
>   order the result

Comment: yup that worked, I added let primarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastname", ascending: true)//by default assume name.  Thanks for your help, would have never guessed that.  I missed that in documentation somehow...